# The button's bordesr are invisiable and no background color

Tags: wpf, xaml

Originally I had a button and worked well. Now I want to make the corners round.

```
<Button Content="Start" x:Name="Start" Style="{StaticResource RoundButtonTemplate}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Margin="20,20,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Width="75"
    Click="Start_Click">
```

In code behind, I set the background color as:

```
Start.IsEnabled = false;
Start.Background = Brushes.Red;
```

In App.xaml:

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="RoundButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border CornerRadius="15"                               BorderThickness="1">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Now the questions are:

1. The background color is gone.
2. The borders of the button are invisible.

How to modify the style?

Comment: Get rid of your codebehind, add `Background` and `IsEnabled` and `BorderBrush` to your Style Template with default Setters and you'll be all done and have done it correctly. It not working the way it is would be expected.

Comment: @ChrisW.But I want to change `Background` and `IsEnabled` dynamically in the code by different conditions. I just want to make border  corners to be round, that is all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the default style of a button http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms753328%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

In your style you define a "border" with a corner radius, but no way to retrieve the color. You should add a Background attribute with {TemplateBinding Background} so that it binds to the Background attribute of your button (Start.Background).

You can always copy the default style and modify it. Also you should have a look at how template bindings work :)